# Android how to ignore auto resizing when keyboard pops up?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

let's say I have a view that is made up of 2 layers -> top layer and bottom layer. I place them both in a frame layout.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- bottom layer -->
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/some_image_you_shouldnt_shrink"/>

    <!-- top layer -->
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/somewhat_transparent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

now, presumably, when i tap on the editText, the keyboard will pop up, and shrink the size of the edit text. However, it seems that the bottom layer is ALSO getting resized. How do i prevent this bottom layer from getting resized?

Note: the framelayout is in a fragment, and the activity that holds this fragment must declare `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`.

EDIT*******************

Just to clarify, i want the editText layer to adjust as high as the keyboard needs to. however, i don't want the image behind it to adjust at all

i only have 1 activity that handles these similar types of fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent a single view from resizing if you set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`. But if you just want to set a non-resizing background, there is a work-around. Instead of setting the background image in the ImageView through XML, add this in your `onCreate()` method

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.some_image_you_shouldnt_shrink);
```

Comment: The default behaviour is supposed to be pan-and-scan. Please try without specifying any mode and if it still doesn't work, try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: interesting. what if i want only certain layouts/fragments to have this, but not all the other fragments? i have only 1 activity so i have to declare either `adjustPan` or not

Comment: this won't work because it doesn't allow my edit-text to resize

Comment: I tried your scenario here and have edited the answer according to what I could do

Answer (score 1):

try this in the manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```